# Login to website and click a button using bash shell

Tags: shell, scripting

I am new to scripting and trying to get a hang with Bash scripting for starters. I am stuck in a situation and need help; I am trying to write a shell script that would login to a website and input the username/password and click on a button. So far I have tried using wget and curl however not had much luck... Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: what did you try out with curl? Is there some place you got stuck?

Comment: You can use Python+Selenium to do it! http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think bash has such capabilities. You can try pytho/mechanize.

Comment: Iam used Python and Selenium and having a tonne of fun with it :)